# raise KeyError(key) KeyError: 'formatters'

Tags: python, logging, alembic

I am creating a simple Flask API. I am using alembic for my database migrations (Postgres). I am getting the following error on my alembic.ini file.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    manager.run()
  File "/Users/omorgan/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 417, i
n run
    result = self.handle(argv[0], argv[1:])
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 386, i
n handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 95, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 215,in migrate
    version_path=version_path, rev_id=rev_id)
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 176, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 427, inrun_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 81, inload_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/Users/admin/.local/share/virtualenvs/cp-api-CkIfmfOt/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 82, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "migrations/env.py", line 12, in <module>
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 959, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
```

My environment:
Python 3.6.5
Pipenv
Mac OSX Mojave

My Alembic file looks like this:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# timezone to use when rendering the date
# within the migration file as well as the filename.
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
#truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; this defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat alembic/versions

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = postgres://crowdplan:cr0wdpl@n@localhost:5432/crowdplan


# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

I have searched all over and it seems like the value is missing form the dictionary, however, it is being passed to the interpreter as listed in the file. This file was auto-generated by alembic when it was initialized.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I ended up removing all migrations, and initializing alembic again for it to work. Not an optimal solution, but I was on a dev database and I had no need whatsoever to return to a previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into same error, I was building application using docker and the root cause was missing "alembic.ini" file.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this issue it was a typo in the filepath. I recommend you verify the file exists just in case, then try load the config file.

Plenty of ways to check that a file exists, a quick google brought up this - https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-check-if-file-exists/

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. I realized I could use Flask-migrate instead of working with alembic directly & was able to run migrations without a hitch:

https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html